# Is changing a question after a bounty was attached to it acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

I was browsing the featured questions and came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816923/gensim-difference-between-expectation-of-dirichlet-and-topic-proportions-given) which caught my attention as a moderator (Brad Larson) had removed an answer made by the OP which was an attempt award the bounty back to the OP (which doesn't seem like something that would be allowed - I don't know all the rules regarding bounties so I could be wrong on this).

Out of curiosity I took a look at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31816923/revisions) and it shows that the OP has changed the question content completely after attaching the bounty, making it a new question - or at least that's what it looks like to me. Worth noting is that a moderator had already reverted it one time.

Is this acceptable behavior?

Comment: "Is changing a question [snip] acceptable?" if its to clarificate it, remove irrelevant parts or expand/add information, yes, its in any circumstance

Comment: Since the question was brought up - no, trying to award yourself your own bounty [*just doesn't work*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998).

Comment: @DrewDormann I suspected that was the case, thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: @Braiam Sure, that should of course be ok, but it wasn't the kind of edit I meant; I guess my question was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Well, he didn't change the question to award himself the bounty.  The somewhat likelier explanation is that he did this to work around a question ban.

Comment: @Braiam: Or fixate the spellification.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, there should be no way to award yourself bounty? So I'm unsure what the possible gains of doing this could be.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I would assume that the possible gain would be to "reuse" the already spent bounty for another question by changing the question text instead of losing the bounty and post a new question (and possibly attach a new bounty). That's just my guess though.

Comment: Possibly, vaguely related: [OP edited question substantially after answer(s) were posted](http://meta.superuser.com/q/9514/354511).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is this acceptable behavior?

No.  It's a foolish and failed attempt to game the system.

The OP tried to change a question to something that they could then answer - so they could award themselves their own bounty.

**It is correct to roll back these clearly-wrong edits to a bountied question**.

As mentioned in my comment above, [these attempts will fail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998) for this very reason.  Bounties would not work if you could attract all the attention and then hand the reputation back to yourself.

I have again reverted [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816923).

Comment: I disagree. There's no answers posted (other than the one by the OP which was deleted), so there's nothing to be invalidated by the question being changed completely. Community consensus is, as far as I'm aware, that completely changing a question that has no answers is perfectly acceptable; I don't see why having attached a bounty changes that.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Where do you find that consensus? The only consensus in that direction is *not* rolling back if the change didn't invalidate answers but a rollback would. Otherwise, support is fairly solid for rolling back.

Comment: @Deduplicator It's entirely possible I'm misremembering, and I can't seem to find the post, so we'll assume I'm incorrect.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I remember a blog post from either JoelOnSoftware or CodingHorror that *supports* your notion that if OP starts an edit war, one should just let them do it and walk away.  I've edited my answer to make it more prominent that it is about questions with a *bounty* - since altering the meaning of those posts present vectors for bounty abuse.

Comment: @DrewDormann The policy is that if the OP starts an edit war that you *flag for a mod to resolve the issue* and *then* walk away because it's a problem that you can't solve, not that it isn't a problem at all.  The mod can then roll back the OP's edit and, if they feel its necessary, lock the post to prevent them from editing it again.

Answer (score 1):

What the user is trying to do doesn't work anyway.  The system prevents bounties from being awarded back to the person who set the bounty.

I'm not sure what the point is in rolling back the edits.  The user might learn more if he experienced the system not awarding him his own bounty even though he made the edits.